# PHP curl seems to be stripping post body

Tags: php, php-curl

I have a PHP curl statement that for some reason is being sent malformed. No matter what, the body being sent out is empty when using the POST method. It's only sending the headers. I can't seem to figure out why.

I am JSON encoding the `$data` payload in the function that is calling this one.

(php5.6 / apache)

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'X-xx-MerchantId: ' . $this->opt['merchantId'],
  'X-xx-REST-API-Key: ' . $this->opt['apiKey'],
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Accept: application/json'
));

if ($method == "POST") {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
}
elseif ($method == "GET") {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
}
elseif ($method == "PUT") {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
}
elseif ($method == "DELETE") {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "PHPxx v2");

$result_text = curl_exec($ch);

$curl_request_info = curl_getinfo($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Using a testing tool for API calls I've verified what curl is sending showing a blank body.

[image]

When testing against the real endpoint, the endpoing returns an error that seems to imply that there is no body. (a 411 status code)

Dump of curl_getinfo($ch):

[image]

Comment: what method are you using to test this? For GET a body is not supposed to be present

Comment: Are you sure that the method is set? Try some echoing/logging in each if statement to make sure it's adding the correct options.

Comment: The post method is the one being fired, I've verified that.

Comment: Is `$data` a string (JSON) or an array?

Comment: JSON. thought I've tried passing an array as well.

Comment: Weird. Can you dump the contents of curl_getinfo then (on post request)?

Comment: Sure Edited the question to show it.

Comment: I doubt it could be the reason but you are not providing a `Content-Length` header. Also, have you tried like that `$data = 'json='.$data.'&'` just to check ?

Comment: AFAIK when you pass data into `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` Content-length is automatically calculated and appended to the headers. As you can see above in the last screenshot it is present in the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you API KEY has two new lines after it. Two newlines indicates "End Of Header, Start the content". So you're confusing the poor thing.

Your first debug shows the "Content-Type" and "Accept" headers are not going through correctly.

Your second debug shows the same two headers are not being used; shows the two newlines,  but also shows you are passing some content.

Remove those newlines and you should be right.

Comment: Why aren't those headers shown in Raw Body section then? Otherwise, looks like a good suggestion, two newlines do separate headers from content.

Comment: That is one thing I couldn't answer (so left out of my answer). This other is that the debug shows it as "here are the headers" including the two extras in the bottom tab, but not in the top part. I can only assume it's confusing the hell out of the debug tool :)

Comment: That is a curious situation, and would be my guess too. Malformed headers can cause all manner of unpredictable behavior. If you @Remog are unable to find why the key has newlines in it, just wrap it in `trim( $this->opt['apiKey'] )` when you give it to curl. At least as a quick test.